# Photo-realism blind experiment

Tags: rendering

I need a lot of real time rendered images and real images where it's recorded which one is which to prove either way whether existing gaming computers have the hardware to be photo-realistic to someone I know (which they will have if they're unable to tell the difference, statistically) at their best. Please can someone link me to what I'm looking for? Thank you.

Comment: http://gizmodo.com/17-amazing-renders-that-youll-swear-are-photographs-1399998593

Answer (score 2):

Path tracing is a common method for making photo realistic images.  If I were you, I'd start off doing a google image search for path tracing to find some images.

You may get lucky and find a site that has a lot of them.

Here are a few examples I found doing that:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: One of the property of all these images which betrays them is that they show ideally clean surfaces. In real world the surfaces are rarely so clean, even in jewelry shops.